# Posting on application profile wall disabled for administrators and developers of the application

Tags: post, profile, facebook-apps

Developers and administrators of one of my applications can not see or add posts on application profile page wall.
Other users can see posts normally. I looked through application setting options several times and tried to change some setting but nothing helped.

Since there are no active restrictions on application, I assume this is a bug.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/?fb_comment_id=fbc_10151045352725697_28279499_10151048487325697#uqk232_2) , application profiles are being removed.

I guess this is why you can't interact with it anymore.

Comment: Well, I 'm aware of the plan for removing application profiles, but I don't think it is the cause of this issue since on my other application (recently published) everything works fine.